# How do I set a default value when looking up a JNDI variable lookup with Log4J 2?

Tags: java, logging, jndi, log4j2

I'm already successfully configuring Log4J 2 with a `log4j2.xml` file, and I'm successfully setting the value of a `Property` in the file via a
[JNDI variable lookup](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html#JndiLookup).

However, I'd like to provide a default value for the `Property` if the JNDI variable doesn't exist.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Root level="${jndi:yourJndiVariableName:-DEFAULT}">
```

Generally all Log4j2 lookups follow this pattern: `${type:key:-defaultValue}`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes: this can be done by using a *default property map:*

```
<Configuration status="DEBUG" name="Example">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="yourJndiVariableName">
            the value used if the JNDI variable cannot be found
        </Property>
    </Properties>

    ... more configuration ...

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="${jndi:yourJndiVariableName}">
            <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>

    ... more configuration ...
</Configuration>
```

[According to the Log4J 2 configuration documentation for property substitution](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#PropertySubstitution), this will also work for the other property origins (such as environment variables, system properties, etc).